# sWidth is not working in dataTables

Tags: datatables

I am trying to fix column `width` instead of dataTable choosing it automatically , hence i am trying to set sWidth but its not applying. Following is my code,

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#Emp_table').dataTable()
            .columnFilter({
           aoColumns: [ {type:"text"},
             { type: "text" },
             { type: "select",bSmart: false,"sType": "string", "sWidth": "5%" },
             { type: "select" },
             { type: "select" },
             { type: "select"},
             { type: "select" },
             { type: "select" }
            ],
          });
         });
```

Here all works fine like filter by text or value except the column width, because of that the table length is extending beyond my page. Even though my first value is ID which is not even more than 3 digits the width takes for around 10 characters . Not only sWidth, even bSmart i am trying to false but still it works with smart filter .

Comment: Have you tried this ?http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width

Comment: I tried the above. But i don't see any changes. I guess since i am using columnFilter the table footer is overriding the changes. If i remove columnFilter then it works fine

Answer (score 4):

You need to set http://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth to false
Also it looks like you're creating your table a bit oddly.

For datatables 1.10 use:

```
$('#Emp_table').DataTable({
  'columns': [
    {"type": "string", "width": "5%" },
    // etc...
  ],
  'autoWidth': false,
})
```